# Using addressables with textures set on materials causes memory leaks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, mobile, addressables

We are using addressables to load in most of our textures. However, we've noticed (using the memory profiler) that when a texture is referenced directly by a material, addressables is unable to unload it when though we've left the scene and tried to unload the assets referenced by that scene.

This seems related to the issue in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/textures-are-referenced-after-asset-release.569860/) however it seems that no one has provided an answer for it.

Our addressables manager handles the decrementing of ref counts on all unused assets. Does anyone have a solution to get around this issue?

Comment: How do you leave the scene? it only automaticaly unloads the assets if the scene loaded as ``LoadSceneMode.Single``. 0 Ref count doesn't mean it will directly unloads it.